Why does the Lebesgue Integral not require countably many sets when the Outer Measure does?
I'm working my way through Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis. In Chapter 3A, The non-negative Lebesgue integral on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ of a function $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is defined as the supremum of all lower Lebesgue sums $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$, each of which takes place over an $\mathcal{S}$-partition $P$ containing a finite collection of disjoint sets $A_1,...,A_m$ of $X$:
$$ \mathcal{L}(f, P) = \sum_{j=1}^m \mu(A_j)\inf_{A_j} f $$
$$ \int f \ d\mu =\sup\left\{\mathcal{L}(f, P): P\text{ is an } \mathcal{S}\text{-partition of }X\right\}$$
In Chapter 2A, the outer measure $|A|$ of a set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ is defined as the infimum of all sums of the lengths of countably many open intervals that cover $A$:
$$|A| = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k): I_1, I_2, ... \text{ are open intervals such that }A\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\right\} $$
Why does the Lebesgue integral only require that the supremum is taken over a set of sums of finitely many sets, whereas the outer measure requires the infimum is taken over a set of sums of countably many intervals?

The distinction lies in the direction of approximation and the nature of the objects being measured.

Lebesgue Integral: Finite partitions are sufficient because we approximate the function $ f $ from below by simple functions. By taking the supremum over all such finite partitions, we can get as close as desired to the true integral value.

Outer Measure: Countable covers are needed because we approximate the set $ A $ from above by open intervals. The infimum over countable covers allows us to capture the "smallest" covering, essential for tightly approximating more complex sets.


So, finite partitions work for integrals due to approximation from below, while countable covers are required for outer measure due to approximation from above.

Bassem's answer provides the general explanation, but after some thought I have some additional detail that did not fit in a comment.
To explain why the Lebesgue integral is defined over finitely many partitions, we can show that an "infinite partition" Lebesgue integral (defined as the supremum of lower Lebesgue sums of countably infinite partitions $\mathcal{L}(f, P_\infty)$) is equal to one defined over finite partitions.
The gist of the proof is as follows. We can clearly see that the Lebesgue integral is $<=$ the infinite partition Lebesgue integral, since any finite partition can be rewritten as an infinite one by appending a sequence of trailing empty sets.
To show that the Lebesgue integral is $>=$ the infinite partition Lebesgue integral, we can map each $\mathcal{L}(f, P_\infty)$ to a sequence of non-decreasing finite lower Lebesgue sums $\mathcal{L}(f, P_n)$ of increasing partition size such that the limit of this sequence is $>=$ the associated $\mathcal{L}(f, P_\infty)$. We do this by taking sequentially more of the sets within the partition $P_\infty$ and creating a finite partition based on these sets. Because the limit of a non-decreasing sequence is its supremum, this shows that the Lebesgue integral is $>=$ the infinite Lebesgue integral.
This proof is possible because we are approaching the function from below in such a way that allows us to map each infinite partition to an appropriate sequence of finite partitions.
This approach does not work for the outer measure because we are not able to produce such a mapping. For the outer measure, we would need to find a mapping from each countably infinite open cover over of $A$ to a sequence of finite open covers of $A$, whose sums $\sum_{k=1}^n l(I_k)$ are non-increasing (since the definition of $|A|$ uses infimum rather than supremum) and have a limit that is $<=$ that of the sum of the infinite case $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)$.
For a counterexample, consider the set of all rationals in the interval (0, 1). There is no sequence of finite open covers for this set that yield a limit that is less than one, whereas this set's outer measure is zero.
